# How to set same height of two divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the height of `info_content` to cover the below rest screen, I tried some jQuery. I am just a beginner so I am unable to do it properly. I would appreciate your help to resolve this problem.

```js
var divHeight = $('.video_content').height();

$('.info_content').css('min-height', divHeight + 'px');
```

```css
content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 40px;
}
.content .inner_content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content {
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content .video_content {
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content .info_content {
  background: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner_content">
    <div class="left_content">
      <div class="video_content">
        Some videos comes here
      </div>
      <div class="info_content">
        Some info text comes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set the height, the min-height property will not work

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not worked

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `height()` to set the height of a matched element.

```
var divHeight = $('.video_content').height(); 
$('.info_content').height(divHeight);
```

Comment: You said you wanted to set the same height for both div. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHeight` to get the height of the window and subtract it with the height of `.video_content`

Check the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pranesh_ravi/szgavxw3/2/

Comment: Is it possible that when we minimize the window the height should automatically adjust now i have to reload the page to see the result

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this edit from your side. Added the jQuery library and did modifications.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function calcHeights() {
    var divHeight = $('.video_content').innerHeight();
    var totalHeight = $('.left_content').innerHeight();
    var infoHeight = totalHeight - divHeight - 20;
    $('.info_content').css('min-height', infoHeight + 'px');
  };
  // The height of.info_content should be 100% to window
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    calcHeights();
  });
  calcHeights();
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.content .inner_content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content {
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content .video_content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content .info_content {
  background: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'arial';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner_content">
    <div class="left_content">
      <div class="video_content">
        <img src="https://mediaarchive.cern.ch/MediaArchive/Video/Public/Movies/CERN/2016/CERN-MOVIE-2016-041/CERN-MOVIE-2016-041-002/CERN-MOVIE-2016-041-002-posterframe-640x360-at-55-percent.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="info_content">
        these height should be till bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like these but only one issue I set a css for 
` .left_content{
 overflow-y:auto;
}` that means i want the left_content scrool when it has more data actully left_content have lot of paragraph's

Comment: So you want to hide it? remove the listener, but if there is a small window and then it goes big it will not recalculate and remain small.

Comment: Not hide actually, it should be Scrollable if there is a lot of text inside of "left_content" class

Comment: Well I think instead of mni-height if i write height in your jquery , It solves my problem

Comment: Ok so finally after changing the "min-height" to "height" , my issue resolved but I want to knw what do you mean by - 
`var infoHeight = totalHeight - divHeight - 20;`
are you trying to remove few space from bottom?

Comment: Calculate the height of the container and subtract the height of video and the 20px from their margins.

Comment: after pressing cntrl + f5 , jquery is not proper , I was trying to resolve since yesterday but not been able to figure out why these problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery.

```
var divHeight = $('.video_content').height(); 
var windowHeight=$(window).height();
var infoHeight=(windowHeight-divHeight);
$('.info_content').css('height', infoHeight+'px');
```